# JSON data parsing cannot understand

Tags: php, json

```
array(2) {
["success"]=>
    string(1) "1"
["return"]=>
    array(125) {
    [0]=>
    array(11) {
    ["marketid"]=>
    string(3) "141"
    ["label"]=>
    string(6) "42/BTC"
    ["primary_currency_code"]=>
    string(2) "42"
    ["primary_currency_name"]=>
    string(6) "42Coin"
    ["secondary_currency_code"]=>
    string(3) "BTC"
    ["secondary_currency_name"]=>
    string(7) "BitCoin"
    ["current_volume"]=>
    string(10) "0.11628537"
    ["last_trade"]=>
    string(12) "223.00000000"
    ["high_trade"]=>
    string(12) "256.88999999"
    ["low_trade"]=>
    string(12) "205.00000000"
    ["created"]=>
    string(19) "2014-01-12 19:35:49"
}
}
```

I was trying to process this in PHP

```
$result = api_query("getmarkets");

$json = json_decode($result);
var_dump($result);
```

I tried many times to start processing this data but how would I start this
I was thinking something like $json['return'][0]['marketid'] would grab the market id.

Comment: This is not JSON… This is PHP print_r() data...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is already php object, so no need to parse as json.

try...

```
$result['return'][0]['marketid']
```

... and delete ...

```
$json = json_decode($result);
```

Comment: thanks, sometimes it's confusing to get mixed with json arrays and JSON objects and whatnot they are tricky I haven't dabbled in it too much, thank you for your kind help.